# Python error in Apache NiFi: Import Error: No module named Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, apache-nifi

I'm new to NiFi. I'm trying to execute a Python script using `ExecuteScript` processor. When I tried a simple script which has no import commands it ran fine and showed output in nifi.StdOut. When I tried to run a script which includes import commands like `import pandas`. It showing the below error:

> Import Error: No module named Pandas

I tried providing the path of the pkgs in the Module directory in properties. But it doesn't workout. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the issue is that pandas is a natively-compiled module (it is written in C) rather than being pure Python. The reason this is a problem is that due to the JSR-223 engine, the Apache NiFi `ExecuteScript` processor uses *Jython* rather than actual *Python*. So Python code is fine to run, but it can't depend on modules that aren't pure Python.

The workaround is to use the `ExecuteStreamCommand` processor to invoke the Python script which depends on pandas via the command-line (i.e. `python my_script_that_uses_pandas.py`). The flowfile content will be streamed to `STDIN` and captured from `STDOUT`. Here's a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49524039/70465) describing this in detail.

Comment: Hi @Andy. I am stuck since many days in this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55606681/how-to-read-files-from-getfilesprocessor-in-nifi  Could you please help me with that

Comment: It looks like you are continuing to put new problems into the same question, which isn't how the site works. I suggest you open a new question with the explicit problem you are encountering. I think the problem is that the flowfile content is passed via `STDIN`, not put into a specific file location which you are trying to reference in your Python code.

Comment: Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55682297/python-script-not-working-in-nifi-using-executestreamcommand-processor .

Comment: Hey Andy, can you help me with the above post. Need some guidance over there.