# Nifi: Cannot import pyspark in ExecuteScript processor

Tags: apache-spark, import, pyspark, jython, apache-nifi

I need to implement ExecuteScript in Nifi in order to do column transposition, and I am using pyspark as means to do that.

But the problem says 
"failed to process due to javax.script.ScriptExeption: ImportError: No module named pyspark in  at line number 1:"

I set the path to spark and pyspark like this for module directory setting in ExecuteScript property.

```
C:\Users\username\Desktop\spark\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\hadoop,
C:\Users\username\Desktop\spark\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\bin\pyspark
```

But it did not work.

I am afraid this is very fundamental issue, could not figure out half a day..

Comment: Are you able to run 'normal' python code this way? Are you able to run the script with pyspark manually on all the relevant nodes?

Comment: For property configuration of ExecuteScript processer, I set python for Script Engine, set the path where my python code with pyspark module locates for Script File, and Module Directory as well as I mentioned above. Followed these examples in the [link](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/75545/executescript-cookbook-part-2.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely because the `pyspark` module is a *natively-compiled* Python module, and Apache NiFi uses *Jython* in the `ExecuteScript` processor. This is a known issue, and the [full explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55638352/70465) is here, as well as some [work-arounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56081668/70465) and [details on options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49524039/70465).

The simplest answer is to use `ExecuteStreamCommand` and pass the necessary flowfile attributes as arguments, and the content as `STDIN`. The output of the Python script will be returned via `STDOUT` and captured as the new flowfile content.

Comment: Thank you. I wrote python script with pandas module and  it worked with ExecuteStreamCommand!