# How to write pythoncode in ExecuteScript processor in apache nifi?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache, apache-nifi

Hi I have to execute below  python code in apache nifi  and my nifi flow is as below 
my python code  is as below (I have ruined it locally it is working fine)  `

```
import pandas as pd
 cdr = pd.read_csv("cdr.csv")
 labels = pd.read_csv("result.csv")
 cdr.rename(mapper={str(value[0]):n for n,value in labels.to_dict(orient='list').items()},  axis=1, inplace=True)
```

and my nifi flow :-
[image]

Here cdr comes from GETSFTP and labels comes from get file processor and here cdr data will come continuously

can anyone help me to write above python code in ExecuteScript processor in nifi

Comment: it will be easier to use [ExecuteStreamCommand](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteStreamCommand/index.html) - it allows to read from STDIN and write to STDOUT. but in this case python must be installed near nifi. if you still want to use ExecuteScript I advice you to start from this article: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/75032/executescript-cookbook-part-1.html

Answer (score 0):

The `ExecuteScript` processor [cannot use native Python modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49524039/70465), only [Jython code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55638352/70465). Try using `ExecuteStreamCommand` to run arbitrary Python code.